# Sparql filter on prefix does not work on dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm new to **SPARQL** hope someone could help me.

The problem is that if I run the following query on [dbpedia sparql](https://dbpedia.org/sparql):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?class WHERE { 
?s a ?class.  
}
```

it returns:
[result query](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fclass%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fs%20a%20%3Fclass.%20%20%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

I would like to **remove the results that has this two prefix**: "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl" and "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema", now the query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?class WHERE { 
?s a ?class.  
FILTER ( !strstarts(str(?class), "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl") ).
FILTER ( !strstarts(str(?class), "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema") ).}
```

but it returns only one result:
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property

If I execute the same query on [istat sparql](http://datiopen.istat.it/sparqlIstat.php) these queries work fine.

So the question is, why **on dbpedia** my queries does **not work** as expected?

Thanks

Comment: it does work as expected. Are you aware of the Virtuoso anytime feature? It just returns what it found in the given **Execution timeout**. clearly, your query is expensive. Increase the timeout from 30s to something higher and hope it's enough. Otherwise, deploy your own DBpedia to have full control of resources. The public DBpedia endpoint is a fair use service, thus, the timeout (and the max. result of rows limited to 10000)

Comment: or use a more efficient filter, e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT ?class WHERE { 
?s a ?class.  
FILTER ( ?class not in (rdf:Property, rdfs:Class, owl:Class, owl:ObjectProperty, owl:DatatypeProperty) )
}`